# Evaluating $\texttt{FermionOperator}$ equality in Openfermion

Tags: programming, chemistry, openfermion

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this kind of question.

I have a simple question about Openfermion. I have two normal ordered `FermionOperator`s `A` and `B` in Openfermion which are not equal. However, when I evaluate `A == B`, it returns `True`. Usually, the equality function seems to work fine, but in this specific case it doesn't seem to work. Below is the source code to replicate this problem.

My question is: why is this happening? I'm wondering if this is maybe a problem with my installation, or perhaps a bug (although, looking at the source code, I cannot see any problems with the equality function). Or maybe I have some sort of conceptual misunderstanding?

---

Source code:

```
from openfermion import FermionOperator, normal_ordered

#string representation of FermionOperators
A_string = '(4.525943261204361+0j) [0^ 0] +\n(-0.3849231244033131+0j) [0^ 1] +\n(0.8547260787716595+0j) [0^ 2] +\n(-1.1299596129151999+0j) [0^ 3] +\n(-0.3849231244033129+0j) [1^ 0] +\n(-4.381884800061626+0j) [1^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(-4.105905711065374+0j) [1^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(-0.944626497232035+0j) [1^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(3.5938875653898616+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(0.5559380952173161+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(-5.184266085346127+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(0.3677762971945129+0j) [1^ 1] +\n(3.6630156211728777+0j) [1^ 2] +\n(-2.5183774065038045+0j) [1^ 3] +\n(0.8547260787716596+0j) [2^ 0] +\n(-4.105905711065371+0j) [2^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(2.0232821070880056+0j) [2^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(0.8540908922866308+0j) [2^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(1.2460804358695565+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(-5.690396818975691+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(3.2577629759360036+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(3.663015621172878+0j) [2^ 1] +\n(-0.360964409584815+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(-0.515120856381232+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(1.2472039494390206+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(1.2551065744601149+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(-0.9446264972320322+0j) [2^ 1^ 1 0] +\n(0.8540908922866324+0j) [2^ 1^ 2 0] +\n(6.764363308219267+0j) [2^ 1^ 2 1] +\n(-0.5061307336295583+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 0] +\n(1.0665005168981174+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 1] +\n(-1.5870659190452852+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 2] +\n(-1.624576120995937+0j) [2^ 2] +\n(2.9075472932497357+0j) [2^ 3] +\n(-1.1299596129151999+0j) [3^ 0] +\n(3.5938875653898643+0j) [3^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(1.2460804358695592+0j) [3^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(-0.5061307336295612+0j) [3^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(4.19902020363552+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(2.44500249921506+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(-1.4836026643174591+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(-2.518377406503804+0j) [3^ 1] +\n(-0.5151208563812295+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(-0.3481302294514168+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(1.6862584012597264+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(3.6148854702404463+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(0.5559380952173167+0j) [3^ 1^ 1 0] +\n(-5.69039681897569+0j) [3^ 1^ 2 0] +\n(1.066500516898118+0j) [3^ 1^ 2 1] +\n(2.445002499215056+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 0] +\n(0.0213735881799324+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 1] +\n(6.043172803857193+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 2] +\n(2.9075472932497357+0j) [3^ 2] +\n(1.2472039494390192+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(1.686258401259725+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(-4.660442362479951+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(-6.470812728417476+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(-5.184266085346124+0j) [3^ 2^ 1 0] +\n(1.2551065744601169+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 2 1 0] +\n(3.6148854702404485+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 1 0] +\n(-6.470812728417465+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 2 0] +\n(-3.4393374365242755+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 2 1] +\n(3.2577629759360045+0j) [3^ 2^ 2 0] +\n(-1.5870659190452812+0j) [3^ 2^ 2 1] +\n(-1.4836026643174585+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 0] +\n(6.043172803857192+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 1] +\n(-0.7285308515736753+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 2] +\n(0.996525236164558+0j) [3^ 3]'
B_string = '(4.525943261204361+0j) [0^ 0] +\n(-0.3849231244033139+0j) [0^ 1] +\n(0.8547260787716593+0j) [0^ 2] +\n(-1.1299596129151999+0j) [0^ 3] +\n(-0.3849231244033138+0j) [1^ 0] +\n(-4.381884800061625+0j) [1^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(-4.105905711065372+0j) [1^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(-0.9446264972320364+0j) [1^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(3.5938875653898648+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(0.5559380952173187+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(-5.184266085346124+0j) [1^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(0.36777629719451244+0j) [1^ 1] +\n(3.6630156211728773+0j) [1^ 2] +\n(-2.518377406503804+0j) [1^ 3] +\n(0.8547260787716591+0j) [2^ 0] +\n(-4.105905711065371+0j) [2^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(2.023282107088007+0j) [2^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(0.8540908922866277+0j) [2^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(1.2460804358695592+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(-5.690396818975689+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(3.257762975936007+0j) [2^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(3.6630156211728773+0j) [2^ 1] +\n(-0.36096440958481857+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(-0.5151208563812304+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(1.2472039494390195+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(1.2551065744601182+0j) [2^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(-0.944626497232038+0j) [2^ 1^ 1 0] +\n(0.8540908922866295+0j) [2^ 1^ 2 0] +\n(6.764363308219268+0j) [2^ 1^ 2 1] +\n(-0.5061307336295606+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 0] +\n(1.0665005168981163+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 1] +\n(-1.5870659190452843+0j) [2^ 1^ 3 2] +\n(-1.624576120995937+0j) [2^ 2] +\n(3.9075472932497366+0j) [2^ 3] +\n(-1.1299596129151999+0j) [3^ 0] +\n(3.5938875653898634+0j) [3^ 0^ 1 0] +\n(1.2460804358695587+0j) [3^ 0^ 2 0] +\n(-0.5061307336295595+0j) [3^ 0^ 2 1] +\n(4.199020203635514+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 0] +\n(2.445002499215058+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 1] +\n(-1.483602664317454+0j) [3^ 0^ 3 2] +\n(-2.518377406503804+0j) [3^ 1] +\n(-0.5151208563812286+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(-0.34813022945142125+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(1.6862584012597162+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(3.6148854702404476+0j) [3^ 1^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(0.5559380952173192+0j) [3^ 1^ 1 0] +\n(-5.690396818975689+0j) [3^ 1^ 2 0] +\n(1.066500516898117+0j) [3^ 1^ 2 1] +\n(2.4450024992150574+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 0] +\n(0.02137358817993462+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 1] +\n(6.043172803857192+0j) [3^ 1^ 3 2] +\n(2.9075472932497366+0j) [3^ 2] +\n(1.247203949439014+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 2 1 0] +\n(1.6862584012597197+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 1 0] +\n(-4.660442362479957+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 2 0] +\n(-6.470812728417478+0j) [3^ 2^ 0^ 3 2 1] +\n(-5.184266085346124+0j) [3^ 2^ 1 0] +\n(1.25510657446012+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 2 1 0] +\n(3.614885470240445+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 1 0] +\n(-6.470812728417472+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 2 0] +\n(-3.439337436524271+0j) [3^ 2^ 1^ 3 2 1] +\n(3.2577629759360067+0j) [3^ 2^ 2 0] +\n(-1.5870659190452825+0j) [3^ 2^ 2 1] +\n(-1.483602664317455+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 0] +\n(6.043172803857192+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 1] +\n(-0.7285308515736739+0j) [3^ 2^ 3 2] +\n(0.996525236164558+0j) [3^ 3]'

#create FermionOperators
A = normal_ordered(FermionOperator(A_string))
B = normal_ordered(FermionOperator(B_string))

#if A and B are equal, A - B should be zero up to numerical precision
print("A - B = {}".format(A - B)) 

#since A and B are not equal, A == B should return False
print("A == B: {}".format(A == B))
```

The output is

```
A - B = (-1.0000000000000009+0j) [2^ 3]
A == B: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug$^1$. Look at following [lines of code](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion/blob/6a2fdacdd77c5101bc47f3d2bde821f0db717b28/src/openfermion/ops/operators/symbolic_operator.py#L635-L636) from the v1.3.0 release branch for the implementation of `SymbolicOperator.isclose` (which implements `FermionOperator.__eq__`):

```
if not (isinstance(a, sympy.Expr) or isinstance(b, sympy.Expr)):
    tol *= max(1, abs(a), abs(b))
```

This occurs inside of a for loop comparing `A` and `B` componentwise. `tol` is provided to `isclose` once at call time, then gets modified by this line to grow larger every time a term of `A` or `B` has a (non-sympy) coefficient greater than 1. If the coefficients of each term in `A` or `B` are all greater than 1, this will eventually corrupt the tolerance after some number of terms and the comparison becomes vacuous.

Here's a minimal reproducing example

```
x = FermionOperator("0^ 0")
y = FermionOperator("0^ 0")
print(EQ_TOLERANCE) # should be 1e-08 for 

# construct two identical operators up to some number of terms
num_terms_before_ineq = 30
for i in range(num_terms_before_ineq):
    x += FermionOperator(f" (10+0j) [0^ {i}]")
    y += FermionOperator(f" (10+0j) [0^ {i}]")
    
# add a final term that is equal within tol but gets missed by the isclose check
xfinal = FermionOperator(f" (1+0j) [0^ {num_terms_before_ineq + 1}]")
yfinal = FermionOperator(f" (2+0j) [0^ {num_terms_before_ineq + 1}]")
# these two terms are not equal within tol..
print(xfinal == yfinal) # >>> False
print(xfinal - yfinal) # (-1+0j) [0^ 31]

# ...but these two terms will be, because the `tol` argument to `isclose` was corrupted
x += xfinal
y += yfinal
print(x == y) # >>> True
print(x - y) # (-1+0j) [0^ 31]
```

If you make `num_terms_before_ineq` a bit smaller then this issue doesn't come up. But in your case there's a ton of terms, so this seems to be exactly what's happening.

---

$^\dagger$ Their intention here *almost* looks like comparing the terms based on a relative difference compared to $\lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert_2$, i.e. check if each term agrees within a relative tolerance $(a_i - b_i) / \text{max}(\lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert_2, \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert_2) \leq \epsilon$. But in that case [the docstring](https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion/blob/6a2fdacdd77c5101bc47f3d2bde821f0db717b28/src/openfermion/ops/operators/symbolic_operator.py#L618-L623) for equality checking is wrong,

```
Comparison is done for each term individually. Return True
if the difference between each term in self and other is
less than EQ_TOLERANCE
```

Comment: in the spirit of open source i went ahead and filed an issue on their github

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and filing the issue on Github. My current work around is using `A - B == 0` instead of `A == B` to check equality, which seems to avoid this issue a lot better.